# Can android certificate fingerprint sha1 use in firebase and Google Place API?

Tags: android, ssl, google-places-api, firebase-authentication, sha1

I would like to know if we can use the same certificate fingerprint SHA1 in Firebase and for Google Maps API?

Before this, I'm using my certificate fingerprint SHA1 for Firebase Sign-In authorization. However, for Google Places API, I have to use a certificate fingerprint SHA1 too. First, I deleted fingerprint SHA1 at Firebase console and add it into Google Places API. Next, I add the fingerprint SHA1 at Firebase,but I'm getting a message saying:

> An error occurred when attempting to modify an Android certificate fingerprint. Please try again later.

And then I tried to deleted the SHA1 in Google API Manager, and put it back into Firebase. And now I'm getting a message saying that:

> The fingerprint that you specified is already being used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project.

when I tried to put SHA1 into Google Places API.

And, both have the same package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key

Yes you can use sha1 in firebase and Google Place API. Because sha1 key generate only one time in same PC .If you want second time then it can not generate.

for more information please follow this link.

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer. It's turns out that my other android project have the same SHA1 key(duplicate). I checked all my project in the Google API Manager and one of the project has SHA1 that auto created by Google Service.

After I deleted the project that I don't want, everything is okay.

Answer (score 0):

I have two project in the firebase console from two different account. I accendently copied the sha1 key from google play console and copied to another account which was not the original app in firbase console. Just delete the unnecessary project or app and also delete the sha1 debug key from original app. Add the debug key again and paste the sha1 key from google play console. It works fine :) You have two key at the end.